# Android BroadcastReceiver in ScrollActivity

Tags: java, android

I had working BroadcastReceiver which notifys user about network status changes, but since i added ScrollActivity to my app, the receiver is not working anymore. So i tried to make a blank ScrollActivity template project to test the reciever and i can see the same - the receiver wont work in apps with ScrollActivity. im a little bit desperate with this situation, would be thankful for help.

I have permissions and receiver registred in manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test_app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ScrollingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".ConnectivityStatusReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here comes the receiver code, which hasnt been called even once in scrollactivity apps yet..

```
package com.example.test_app;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;

public class ConnectivityStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       //THIS HASNT BEEN CALLED EVEN ONCE YET SINCE SCROLLACTIVITY

        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        Log.d("RECIEVER_LOG", "intent:"+intent.getAction());
        if(activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()){
            Log.d("NETWORK_LOG", "connected.");
        }else{
            Log.d("NETWORK_LOG", "not connected.");
        }

        if (activeNetworkInfo == null){
            //no connection activity opens on connection loss
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context , NoInternetConnection.class));
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Scrolling activity itself, untouched as Android Studio generated it

```
package com.example.test_app;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        CollapsingToolbarLayout toolBarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        toolBarLayout.setTitle(getTitle());

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_scrolling, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Could you add class for ScrollActivity?

Comment: @AlexeyBilousov Sorry for delay, added the code !